# What do we mean by the status: Application in Amended stage

Tags: india

The status of an Indian  patent post-examination is "Application in Amended stage"

What do we understand from this status?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking a response in context of Indian patent office examination, as this is mostly seen in IPO.

When an examination is made for a patent application the patent examiner issues FER( first examination report) citing the defects in application including claims,  to address all the deficiency identified in patent application by the examiner  the applicant needs amends patent claims through an amendment.

Indian patent office uses the phrase for  application under amendment during that phase.